# Cannot see the information about cut-off frequency?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US7312598](https://www.google.com/patents/US7312598)

As title, only see the description about phase margin > 60 degree, but cannot see the cut-off frequency in Fig 3 & 4. May I ask where the location of 0dB gain is? Tks.